# How to add arrows for thumbnail jssor navigation slider

Tags: jssor

I check out a demo in jssor site using navigation arrows for thumbnail slider (http://www.jssor.com/demos/thumbnail-navigator-with-arrows.html), but I didn't find example code. Can someone explain how to add arrows to a thumbnail slider?.

Comment: extract jssor.slider.fullpack.zip, find 'demos-jquery\thumbnail-navigator-with-arrows.source.html'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, now it works using the thumbnail skin and ArrowNavigatorOptions from demos-jquery\thumbnail-navigator-with-arrows.source.html as you suggested.